# What is the limits of this specific function?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ x*[2sin\frac{1}{x}]=?$$

When I use the sandwich method, I get that the limit = 0. is that correct?

Comment: Yes! Since $\sin{x}\in[-1,1]\,\forall x$ the limit is $0$

Comment: Indeed. See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1q95lrhucv)

Comment: While "sandwich method" will suffice for approach, and is correct, you may post more rigorous details in an answer below if needed.

Comment: Guys, someone edit my question, now I rolled it back, It is [2sin(1/x)] and not 2sin(1/x)

Comment: By putting the square brackets, are you invoking the greatest integer function  $[x]$? If it is an ordinary bracket then it does not make a difference if the $2$ is outside/inside.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes I am referring to the greatest integer function,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite as:

$x [Sin \frac{1}{x}]=\frac {[sin{\frac{1}{x}]}}{\frac{1}{x}}$

Using L'Hopital rule we get:

$\lim_{x→0} x [Sin \frac{1}{x}]= \lim_{x→0}[ Cos \frac{1}{x}] $

$\ Cos x∈ \{-1, 1\}$

Therefore:

$\lim_{x→0} [Cos \frac{1}{x}]=0 $